# Classical v/s Bayesian Hypothesis Testing

Tags: probability, statistical-inference, bayesian, hypothesis-testing

This question has 2 parts:

(1) What is the fundamental difference between classical and bayesian hypothesis testing? How do I interpret this difference.

(2) Here is a paragraph quoted from Casella and Berger Statistical Inference (Section 8.2):

[image]

I don't understand:

(i) Why is P(H0 is True | X) = {either 0 or 1} ?? --- if I toss a coin I know that I'll get either heads or tails but I do not say that the probability of getting heads is 0 or 1 if the outcome is unknown.

(ii) Why do these probabilities not depend on X?

Answer (score 0):

With the coin tossing, the quantity of interest in the distribution is the probability the outcome is heads/tails. This is a fixed and constant number in the classical paradigm. For a fair coin, this probability is $0.5$ irrespective of whether you get an actual heads or tails (i.e. irrespective of the data X) and $P(H_0: p=0.5|X)=1$.

Comment: Oh that I understand. But by using the cin example what I meant is that since you dont know the parameter, how can you say that the probability of the parameter being in a given set is either 0 or 1? Why not something else

Comment: @KrishnkantSwarnkar The parameter is fixed. It does not have a distribution. The probability a probability lies in the set [0,1] is 1. The probability a probability lies in the set [2,3] is zero, despite not knowing the probability a-priori. It's like a confidence interval for a parameter, the true parameter lies in the confidence interval with either probability 1, or 0.

Comment: Now I do realize what u r trying to say... Thanks :-)